# SQL Query.unable to find the asset count

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables Assets_In and Assets_Out.I would like to know my Assets in Stock.

Assets_IN

```
ASSET_TYPE  ASSET_IN_COUNT
Laptops             3
Desktops            2
Desktops            2
Laptops             2
Laptops             2
Keyboards           5
Keyboards           5
Monitors            4
AC Adapters         3
Mouse               10
Monitors            2
Monitors            2
Backpacks           10
Desktops            2
Backpacks           3
```

Asset_Out

```
ASSET_TYPE  ISSUED_TO
Desktops    Ram
Monitors    Shyam
Keyboards   Ranjan
```

I have written 2 queries but I am not able to combine both these to achieve my result.

```
SELECT ASSET_TYPE Asset, SUM(ASSET_IN_COUNT) Count 
FROM ASSETS_IN GROUP BY ASSET_TYPE
```

**This gives me how many assets we have received**

```
SELECT ASSET_TYPE Asset,COUNT(ASSET_TYPE) 
FROM ASSETS_OUT  GROUP BY ASSET_TYPE
```

**It shows how many assets we have issued.**

The result should show how many assets we have in stock. i.e is Assets in hand minus Assets Issued. Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.Asset, a.Asset_in, b.Asset_issued, a.Asset_in - b.Asset_issued 
from
    (SELECT ASSET_TYPE Asset, SUM(ASSET_IN_COUNT) Asset_in Count 
     FROM ASSETS_IN 
     GROUP BY ASSET_TYPE) a

join

    (SELECT ASSET_TYPE Asset,COUNT(ASSET_TYPE) Asset_issued 
     FROM ASSETS_OUT 
     GROUP BY ASSET_TYPE) b

on a.Asset = b.Asset
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ASSET_TYPE AS Asset
, SUM(ASSET_IN_COUNT) - (SELECT COUNT(ASSET_TYPE) FROM ASSETS_OUT 
WHERE ASSET_TYPE=AI.ASSET_TYPE) AS [Count] 
FROM ASSETS_IN AI GROUP BY ASSET_TYPE
```